# Whats the best way to live update a webpage when the value in a text file changes?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sockets, websocket

I have a webpage that displays the content of text files on a linux server, the data is collected every 5 seconds.
At the moment i use Ajax to get the latest value from the file, and then update a `HTML <div>` accordingly.
I have around 10 text files that are displayed on a page, so i have 10 ajax scripts that grab the latest values of each file.
This appeared to work quite well until recently, i have noticed that at the bottom of Google-Chrome i receive this error:

```
Waiting for available socket
```

The page then crashes.

This only happens on my page that contains the live updates, so i assume this is causing the issue.
I have done some research and found that the best way to update the page would be to use websockets that tell the page when a new value is in the text file, before updating the page, however i am not sure how to use websockets and i can not find a working example.

What is the most efficient way to live update a webpage based on the content of a text file without exhausting browser and webserver resources?

A working example of a script of how i can acheive this would be great.

Here is an example of the Ajax script i am currently using to poll data:

```
<script>
        function table() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'get-text-file.php',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(response){
                    $('.div1').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
                                table();
        setInterval(table, 3600000);
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you creating a new AJAX connection on every poll?  You should be reusing connections, especially with such a short polling interval.  On the other hand, if you do switch to WebSockets, then you can definitely reuse connections and utilize server-side pushes, then you don't have to poll at all anymore.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i don't think my ajax script is re-using connections, i have added an example, how can i change it to re-use connections?